# Magento content in CMS block from PHTML file

Tags: magento-2.1, cms-block

I know many people have asked this question before, but I've tried every combination I can find and I'm not succeeding, so I need some advice in case I am missing something out.

I'm trying to add the contents of a PHTML file to a CMS Block in Magento (V2.2.1)

The theme is called Infortis/ultimo

```
/app/code/Infortis/Ultimo
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo
```

I've made a child theme Infortis-child/ultimo

```
/app/code/Infortis-child/Ultimo
/app/design/frontend/Infortis-child/ultimo
```

I've tried the following combinations in the CMS Block

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Infortis_ultimo::custombox.phtml"}}
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Infortis-child_ultimo::custombox.phtml"}}
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_customboxmaker::custombox.phtml"}}
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="customboxmaker::custombox.phtml"}}
```

I've added the custombox.phtml to the following locations and none of them are loading the content into the CMS Block.

```
/vendor/customboxmaker/custombox.phtml
/app/design/frontend/Infortis-child/ultimo/custombox.phtml
/app/code/Infortis/Ultimo/view/frontend/templates/custombox.phtml
/vendor/customboxmaker/templates/custombox.phtml
/app/design/frontend/Infortis-child/ultimo/templates/custombox.phtml
```

Please can somebody confirm what I need to add to the CMS Block and the exact path location of the custombox.phtml file?

Do I need to add anything to the /app/design/Infortis-child/ultimo/etc/local.xml file as none of the examples I've found so far have indicated this is required?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing templates folder

```
/vendor/customboxmaker/templates/custombox.phtml

/app/design/frontend/Infortis-child/ultimo/templates/custombox.phtml

/app/code/Infortis/Ultimo/view/frontend/templates/custombox.phtml
```

You can call your template directly in cms block using

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  template="custombox.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I was really hoping that was it! It's still not loading though, I've copied the file to the 3 locations as per your post and the cms block entry. I have cache turned off too. Thank you so far

Comment: Have Deployed your content??

Comment: I havent deployed since I first installed it, could that be what I'm missing as I've added files? (php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy)?

Comment: Yes u need to deploy conttents whenever crreating a module or creating nrew phtml

Comment: I've deployed, but oddly the templates folder and custombox.phtml file  dont appear in /pub/static/frontend/Infortis-child/ultimo/en_US (or en_GB), the parent theme doesnt have the templates folder by default.

Comment: just copy paste those files in pub folder and check whether it is displaying or not in frontend

Comment: The parent Infortis/ultimo theme has a parent of its own, called base, I've added the file to the templates folder there and then deployed, which has worked, but this is the wrong answer as it should be in the child theme I've created and not the grand-parent. 
This is the path that worked: app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/templates/custombox.phtml

Comment: Thanks Aravind, I think I discovered a new bug, but could be related to this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3754. If you have a child of a child theme, the grand-child theme doesn't deploy and mirrors the parent theme like for like.